# Mock function in typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following code to mock:

```
const P = {
    scripts: {
        getScripts: (name?: any) => {
            // do some stuff and return json
            return { foo: 'value'};
        }
    }
}
export default P;
```

The code I need to test:

```
export const getScripts = (name?: string) => {
   return P.scripts.getScripts(name); // I want a mock being called here
};
```

I manage to use sinonJS for my tests:

```
const fakeGetScript = sinon.fake.returns({
    foo: 'fakeValue'
});
```

but I can't figure how to replace the original `getScript` of `P` with my fake.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxyquire is nice, but it doesn't maintain your typescript types. [ts-mock-imports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mock-imports) is a library that is specifically designed for replacing imports with fakes and it is built on top of sinon. It is also type safe.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass `P` as a collaborator to make mocking easier instead of intercepting the `require` with **proxyquire**?

```
export const getScripts = (name?: string, P) => {
   return P.scripts.getScripts(name); // I want a mock being called here
};

// Test
const fakeGetScript = () => ({ foo: 'value' });
const P = { scripts: { getScripts: fakeGetScript } };

expect(getScripts('aName', P)).toEqual({ foo: 'value' });
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you need to intercept the creation of the module you are importing. Sinon cannot do this. One way to achieve this is through the [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) library.

It would go something like this:

```
const proxyquire =  require('proxyquire');
const fakeGetScript = sinon.fake.returns({
    foo: 'fakeValue'
});
const p = proxyquire('./path/to/p', {
  scripts: {
    getScripts: fakeGetScript
  }
});
```

Then you can run your assertions on fakeGetScript as you expect.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but your solution is close to what I'm looking for but since I'm using `import` instead of `require`, it seems that proxyquire cannot help me.

Comment: There is no contradiction. You can use proxyquire for your tested modules (in your test modules). And import everywhere else.

Comment: Well, I should mis something. 
My code import P like that:
`import P from 'path/to/api'`
As I understand, proxyquire inject the fake when the object to mock is imported with `require`
Sorry for my noob questions, I'm really new in JS testing, and therefore, in TS testing...

Comment: Right, so in your test code, do not do `import P from 'path/to/api`. Instead, do `const P = proxyquire('path/to/api', { ... })`. You need to test the module with proxied dependencies, not the actual module.

Comment: No, you don't need to. Proxyquire is only necessary in test code. It's that in your test code, rather than importing the module under test directly, you need to import it using proxyquire.